# How to create a new column based on minimum value from another column

Tags: python, dataframe, loops, minimum

I have a dataframe with a lot of columns and rows (> 10000), but I need to create a column based on the minimum value from another one

Example dataframe:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cru45.png)

So, I need the column `"Cantidad min"` to contain the minimum value for that group of `"CodProducto"`:

Example:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QBJ7l.png)

How can I do in python?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) Try to create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Is this a [tag:pandas] dataframe? Please provide your data in a way we can actually use it (see [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](//stackoverflow.com/q/20109391/843953)).

Comment: Your question is a duplicate of this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51074911/pandas-get-minimum-of-one-column-in-group-when-groupby-another

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try follow one.

```
dataframe["Cantidad min"] = df.groupby(dataframe)["CodProducto"].min()
```

I can't test this code on your data because you didn't share yours. If it doesn't works, please provide me your data as .csv format.