Vectorize the operation of finding the lowest value of a column in dataframe groups defined by another column
I have the following dataframe:
df = pd.DataFrame(
data = [
        [0,0],
        [1,0],
        [2,2],
        [3,3],
        [4,3],
        [5,3],
        [6,4],
        [7,4],
    ],
    columns = ['day_count', 'level']
)

I am wondering if there is a vectorizable way to calculate the lowest value of the day_count column in each level group to produce this output:
df.groupby(['level'])['day_count'].transform('min')


This is an operation that is part of an expensive optimization function call on a large dataset, and I want to see if it's possible to produce this through a series of vectorizable operations to speed things up and to possibly lump multiple calls together.
My attempts so far focus on trying to produce shifts of the level column and use it to take differences and perform numpy where logic on the differences to identify the beginnings of groups and extract the day_count value at those points. But either way I find myself having to perform some sort of sequential scan that would not be vectorizable.

Images of data are not acceptable, please provide a [mre] as text

@mozway thx, updated.

Trying to see if piRsquared's answer in this thread would do the job:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51074911/pandas-get-minimum-of-one-column-in-group-when-groupby-another

@Mike: is the dataframe sorted? In your example each level starts with the lowest value, and the levels follow each other consecutively. If that's the case, you could use e.g.: df['day_count'].where(df['level'].ne(df['level'].shift())).ffill().

@ouroboros1 That does it, my data is sorted. If you post this as an answer I'll accept it, thank you.

Glad to help! Yeah, the issue is that the question is now closed, so I suppose you could [edit] it to make clear that your data is sorted and that the lowest value will always be the first value for each consecutive level. You can then vote to reopen. Once reopened, I could add the answer. Or maybe someone else will; also fine :). Anyway, good to hear it works; happy coding!
